# C program getting stuck and doesn't even enter main

Tags: c, gcc, runtime-error

I wrote the following code for FCFS scheduling.
The problem is that this code is compiling fine, but after executing `./a.out`, nothing is displayed and the program is stuck. It doesn't even print the `"Reading"` `printf` statement at beginning of `main()`. What is the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct process
{

  int at;
  int bt;
  int wt;
  int tt;
  int rt;
  char pid[5];

} p[5];

int i, j;
int n = 0;

void main()
{
  printf("Reading");
  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen("in1.txt", "r");
  char sample;
  if (fp != NULL )
  {
    sample = getc(fp);
    while (sample != EOF);
    {
      if (sample == '\n')
        n++;
      sample = getc(fp);
    }
    fseek(fp, 0, 0);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      fscanf(fp, "%s %d %d", p[i].pid, &p[i].at, &p[i].bt);
      p[i].wt = p[i].tt = 0;
      p[i].rt = p[i].bt;
    }
    fclose(fp);
  }
  //sorta();
  printf("\nGantt Chart for FCFS\n");

  int t = 0;
  int avgw = 0;
  int avgt = 0;
  printf("%d ", t);
  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    if (p[i].at > t)
    {
      printf("%d ", t);
      t = p[i].at;
    }
    p[i].wt = t - p[i].at;
    avgw = avgw + p[i].wt;
    printf("%s ", p[i].pid);
    p[i].tt = p[i].bt + p[i].wt;
    avgt = avgt + p[i].tt;
    t = t + p[i].bt;
    printf("%d ", t);
    printf("\navg waiting time = %d", avgw / n);
    printf("\navg turn around time = %d", avgt / n);
  }
}
```

Comment: It is printing :
Reading
Gantt Chart for FCFS
0.
What compiler are you using?

Comment: Small remark: `p[5]` and later having `i` run from `0` up to `n - 1`, which might be more than `4`, will cause a buffer overflow, with any file that has enough lines.

Comment: Please indent your code before posting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Standard output is line buffered. Change "Reading" to "Reading\n", and you will see it.

Then you have a mistake here:

```
while (sample!=EOF);
```

The body of that while loop is just the semicolon, not the block afterwards! If the condition is true, your program will get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: Got it. But why won't it execute after that?

Comment: Thank you! Just found it now!

Comment: Also `getc` returns an int, not a char. So the while loop will never compare equal to EOF, since EOF is typically defined as an integer constant > 255.

Comment: @Lundin: que?  EOF is guaranteed to be a negative value (ISO/IEC 9899:2011 §7.21.1: '`EOF`
[...] expands to an integer constant expression, with type `int` and a negative value').  You're right about `getc()` returns an `int`, but the loop termination depends on whether plain `char` is signed or unsigned.  If it is signed, then character code 0xFF (ÿ) will trigger EOF prematurely; if it is unsigned, you have an infinite loop because no unsigned char value equals -1 ever.

Answer (score 1):

Do write the following staements at the top i.e. after `void main`

```
int t =0;
int avgw=0;
int avgt=0;
```

and remove the `;` after

```
 while (sample!=EOF)
```

Comment: Moving the declarations is only necessary if you use a retrograde compiler (one that does not support C99 or later).